# Increase FD limitation then SSH not working?

Tags: linux, ssh, kernel, centos, file-descriptor

I'm using CentOS 6.3 64bit, and having trouble with increase FD limitation: SSH not working after changed the limitation, every-times I logged on my server, after typed password, then "connection closed by remote server".

It's a remote server without any "rescue mode" so there's no way to do a local login to get any error log. I also tried ulimit -SHn before this issue happened but not work as well.

Now I have to restore snapshot every-time this issue happened, and still have no idea what's wrong with my server.

Since I'm working on a high performance server handling millions of requests per second, I need a very high FD limitation, here is my configuration:

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
* hard nofile 2000000
* soft nofile 2000000


/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf  
*          soft    nproc     1024


/etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server


/etc/pam.d/sshd
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    required     pam_limits.so   


/etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 2000000
fs.nr_open = 2000000
```

Comment: Can you explain precisely what a "request" is? Is this an operation over an already-open network connection? Or does this involve a TCP setup and teardown? Or what? And millions a *second*? Really?

Comment: Hi, this is Off Topic. I see that you also asked this on [SF], where it is on topic (as otherwise I'd have suggested you do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2^20 is the absolute limit. At a minimum you'd have to change `NR_OPEN` in `linux/fs.h`.

```
#define NR_OPEN (1024*1024) /* Absolute upper limit on fd num */
```

I would not suggest raising the `limit.conf` value any higher than you have to. Many programs try to close every file descriptor they could possibly open, particularly before calling `exec`. They would loop for an awfully long time closing descriptors that weren't open.

Comment: Is there another way instead of modify source code? Since deploy modified kernel is not acceptable in my remote server.

Comment: Another way to do what? You haven't told us what your outer problem is in any kind of detail that would allow us to suggest solutions.

Comment: Wait a second... but why SSH not working? I haven't find any info about increase FD limitation can break SSH

Comment: All kinds of things will break if you exceed 2^20. It's a kernel limitation. It's like putting wings on your car and trying to fly. We know something bad will happen, just not what.

Comment: But I think it's not that easy, 2^20(including my "* hard nofile 2000000") is just a "literal" limitation, kernel takes no action before FD actually reached 2^20. I agree your opinion that not raising the limit higher than what I actually need, but there's still worth trying to explore overcome this kernel limitation.

Comment: The kernel does take action before the FD actually reaches 2^20. It reports the increased limits to applications, which then make decisions based on the invalid information, likely attempting operations on descriptors that can't actually be accessed returning error codes they don't expect.